# Salesforce Field Services Response Times

Tags: api, mulesoft, cloud

Does Salesforce Field Services set expectations to API response times? Is those SLA's documented in Salesforce Legal Documents?

Answer (score 0):

There is no guaranteed SLA response time, because it would be possible for customers to set up automations that exceed this SLA. There are not even SLAs for Salesforce itself, nor have they needed it with their 99.9%+ uptime over the past 23 years of service.